# IIF with ISNULL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
    SELECT first_name, last_name
    (SELECT  ISNULL(IIF(getdate() between vacation_start and vacation_end, 1, 0),0) from vacatoin_request where mat_emp = W.mat_emp) as is_on_vacation,
    (SELECT  ISNULL(IIF(getdate() between mission_start and mission_end, 1, 0),0) from mission_order where mat_emp = W.mat_emp) as is_on_mission
    FROM
    workers W
```

IIF is working fine but when I add ISNULL, It's still returning null If that worker have no vacation requests or mission orders in the other tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the select returns NULL so `ISNULL` needs to be outside the select

```
 SELECT first_name, last_name
    ISNULL((SELECT TOP 1 IIF(getdate() between vacation_start and vacation_end, 1, 0) from vacatoin_request where mat_emp = W.mat_emp),0) as is_on_vacation,
    ISNULL((SELECT TOP 1 IIF(getdate() between mission_start and mission_end, 1, 0) from mission_order where mat_emp = W.mat_emp),0) as is_on_mission
FROM
workers W
```

Comment: I will, It's asking me to wait 3 minutes.

Comment: @Hackawar , you should put  'Top 1'  in inner select to be in safe side

Comment: Edited with @KumarHarsh 's note

Comment: @KumarHarsh can someone explain why the TOP 1 is necessary in this case?

Comment: if by chance inner query return more than 1 rows then query will throw error.So to make sure ite return only one rows include top 1. Also by including Top 1 performance will improve only.

Comment: @KumarHarsh vacation_request could have multiple rows for the same user though. If I use TOP 1, It's possible that It will take the wrong row and return 0 for 'is_on_vacation' since It didn't read the other rows? or I'm missing something?

Comment: @Hackawar , if vacation_request could have multiple rows for the same user then you have no choice than use (Top 1) now you have to write correct condition ,so that it return correct value.Even if you use Tapaksh query below then you hv to apply correct condition.better throw sample data

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    first_name, last_name
    CASE WHEN v.mat_emp IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END   as is_on_vacation
    CASE WHEN m.mat_emp IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END   as is_on_mission
FROM
    workers         W   
LEFT JOIN 
    vacatoin_request    v
ON 
    v.mat_emp = W.mat_emp       AND
    getdate() between v.vacation_start and v.vacation_end
LEFT JOIN 
    mission_order       m   
ON
    m.mat_emp = W.mat_emp       AND
    getdate() between m.mission_start and m.mission_end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT first_name, last_name
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT v.mat_empt) from vacatoin_request v where v.mat_emp = W.mat_emp and getdate() between vacation_start and vacation_end) as is_on_vacation,
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT m.mat_emp) from mission_order m where m.mat_emp = W.mat_emp and getdate() between mission_start and mission_end) as is_on_mission
    FROM
    workers W
```